# How to add parameters in a url in render method - Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-pagination

How to add parameters in a url in render method - Django?

I'm having difficulty adding pagination to a search result.

On the first page the result is shown perfectly, but from the second page onwards, the search parameter no longer exists.

thank you.

```
def get(self, request):

    clientes = Cliente.objects.filter(
        Q(nome__icontains=request.GET['nome']))

    formPesquisa = FormPesquisaCliente()

    paginator = Paginator(clientes, 40)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    clientes = paginator.get_page(page)

    response = render(request, 'cliente/index.html', {
        'clientes': clientes,
        'formPesquisa': formPesquisa})

    response['Location'] += '?nome=' +request.GET['nome']
    return response
```

Comment: When on clicking second page you need to pass `nome` object in the url again.

Comment: Can you show the html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you missing is that when you have filtered data from the queryset and its paginated so obviously to view the next page you need to maintain the state by passing the same filter object `nome`. So the url should look something like this.

**`http://localhost:8000/clients/?page=2&nome=something`**

```
def get(self, request):
abc = request.GET.get['nome'])     #<--- variable to get value from view
clientes = Cliente.objects.filter(
    Q(nome__icontains=abc))               #<-- pass the abc variable  here

formPesquisa = FormPesquisaCliente()

paginator = Paginator(clientes, 40)
page = request.GET.get('page')
clientes = paginator.get_page(page)

response = render(request, 'cliente/index.html', {
    'clientes': clientes,
    'formPesquisa': formPesquisa,
    'abc':abc})                                      #<-- passing the abc variable to view to maintain the state of your filter.

response['Location'] += '?nome=' +request.GET['nome']
return response
```

Example Pagination Code:

```
<div class="pagination">
  <span class="step-links">
      {% if clients.has_previous %}
          <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          {% if nome %}
          <a href="?page={{ clientes.previous_page_number }}&nome={{ nome }}">previous</a>
            {% else %}
          <a href="?page={{ clientes.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
            {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <span class="current">
          Page {{ clientes.number }} of {{ clientes.paginator.num_pages }}.
      </span>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      {% if clientes.has_next %}
            {% if nome %}
                <a href="?page={{ clientes.next_page_number }}&nome={{ nome  }}">next</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="?page={{ clientes.paginator.num_pages }}&nome={{ nome  }}">last &raquo;</a>
            {% else %}
                <a href="?page={{ clientes.next_page_number }}">next</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="?page={{ clientes.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
            {% endif %}

      {% endif %}
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much